# What's the meaning of ".." in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

When plotting a contour plot, "..level.." is used in the code.

```
ggplot(faithful, aes(eruptions, waiting)) + stat_density2d(aes(colour = ..level..))
```

When plotting a barplot, "..count.." is used.

```
x <- sample(c('A','B','C','D'), size = 1000, replace= TRUE, prob = c(0.2,0.3,0.3,0.2))
y <- rnorm(1000) * 1000 
df = data.frame(x= x, y = y)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = factor(x), y = ..count..))+ geom_bar(stat = 'count')
```

If we replace "..count.." with "count", an error occurs. So what is the difference?

Comment: dot is valid character in a variable name so `..count..` and `count` are two different variables.  Note that in  ggplot2 3.0 that `..count..` is no longer used and instead one uses `stat(count)`.  See https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2018/07/ggplot2-3-0-0/

Comment: `..x..` isn't special in R. It is (was) only special to ggplot in the sense that ggplot would create variables with those names for you. But in general you can use periods in any variable name however you like just like any other letter.

Answer (score 0):

`..count..` is an identifier just like any other identifiers in R, because `.` is just a normal character that can be used in an identifier in R — unlike in other programming languages, where it is usually a special operator. Remember that in R you can define a variable named `data.set`:

```
data.set <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=4:6)
```

And the period in the variable name is just a normal identifier character like letters.

It just happens that `..count..` is an identifier chosen by `ggplot` to represent one of its features, a count-based density estimate.